# In Cypress, can I turn off "Ancestor had position: static and had overlap so could not be found"?

Tags: cypress

I have to set `position:static` on my html tag because I need to disable chrome's default swipe left to go back (we use the same gesture elsewhere in the app)

However, this breaks many of my cypress tests, often where `should('be.visible')` is used.

Is there any way to turn off the `position: static` ancestor checking?

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the issue. If I test `<div style="position: static;">Something</div>` then `.should('be.visible')` passes. Are you using an older Cypress version? Is there an example element that reproduces the error?

Comment: Note, if there is no text inside the `<div>`, I have a fail because effective height is 0. But it also errors when there is no `position: static` style. Is that the problem you are getting?

Comment: Thanks @Fody! The issue seems to be when there is some partial overlapping. I will create a reproducible case and get back to you.